# Is it possible that messages on a kafka partition block?

Tags: apache-kafka, sarama

I am using sarama kafka consumer which has a MaxProcessingTime of 250ms.
When i send a large message ~400000 bytes, the partition gets blocked, i.e., my kafka consumer stops reading from that partition and the lag on that partition keeps on increasing. Is this possible because of MaxProcessingTime value?

Comment: Could you show related code and have you tried to get some logs from where the consumer blocks ?

Comment: I have same issue. Did you figure out the root cause?

Comment: @Viktor didn't figure the root cause but upgrading sarama and sarama-cluster (consumer libraries) to latest version did the trick for me